# How feasible it to combine Proof of Work and Proof of Elapsed time consensus to create a custom blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, bitcoin, proof-of-work

I wonder if it feasible to create your own custom consensus by combining Proof of Work and Proof of Elapsed time?

How would I approach it? Any tools or frameworks to build it?

I appreciate all the comments.

Comment: You might get more responses if you elaborate on design goals.

Comment: The design goals are the following:                                                                           
1)  Create an ecosystem of applications that include functionality like providing a reputation/identity, exchange tokens, send/receive funds, fundraising etc.                                 
2)  Target block time to be 5 seconds 3) Ideally achieve  transaction rate at 12+ transactions per second